# Unexpected token at Object.parse (native) in angular2 package.json

Tags: angular, package.json

I'm getting an error from angular2 module while starting my sails app :

```
[0] error: SyntaxError: /node_modules/angular2/ts/package.json: Unexpected token <
[0]     at Object.parse (native)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:412:27)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[0]     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
[0]     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
[0]     at node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
[0]     at Array.forEach (native)
[0]     at requireAll (/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
[0]     at /node_modules/include-all/index.js:54:23 [SyntaxError: /node_modules/angular2/ts/package.json: Unexpected token <]
```

The error seems to come from this package.json :

```
{
  "name": "angular2",
  "version": "<%= packageJson.version %>",
  "description": "Angular 2 - a web framework for modern web apps",
  "homepage": "<%= packageJson.homepage %>",
  "bugs": "<%= packageJson.bugs %>",
  "contributors": <%= JSON.stringify(packageJson.contributors) %>,
  "license": "<%= packageJson.license %>",
  "repository": <%= JSON.stringify(packageJson.repository) %>,
  "devDependencies": <%= JSON.stringify(packageJson.defaultDevDependencies) %>,
  "peerDependencies": {
      "es6-promise": "<%= packageJson.dependencies['es6-promise'] %>",
      "es6-shim": "<%= packageJson.dependencies['es6-shim'] %>",
      "reflect-metadata": "<%= packageJson.dependencies['reflect-metadata'] %>",
      "rxjs": "<%= packageJson.dependencies['rxjs'] %>",
      "zone.js": "<%= packageJson.dependencies['zone.js'] %>"
  }
}
```

By adding double quotes around contributors, devDependencies and repository properties, I have no longer the error but I guess it's not the solution to update a file in node_modules/angular2..

Does everyone have an idea how to fix it ? Thank you in forward for your help :)

Comment: I guess that there are some processing done at startup for this file. Could you give us more details about them?

Comment: I don't know how to find this, here is the file I mentionned https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/package.json maybe it could help. Thanks for helping.

Comment: In fact, this file should be used when starting your application. The Angular2 part, I mean... The <%= ... %> elements are something that are preprocessed. It think that should use the `package.json` file described in this page instead: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this file shouldn't be used when starting the Angular2 part of your application. The `<%= ... %>` elements are something that needs to be preprocessed since it's not a valid JSON.

It think that should use the `package.json` file described in this page instead: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart instead of the one you mentionned from the Angular2 repository (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/package.json). The latter is for the project internally not for applications based on Angular2...

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I was using the root package.json from my sails app for declaring angular2 dependencies. By using a new one in the public directory where there is my angular2 application, it works.

Is this a good practise to have one package.json for server side and another one for the client side or should I try to find why the root package.json is causing this problem while having angular2 dependencies on it ?